# Recommendations for .NET compression library

Tags: c#, compression

I am looking for some recommendations about compressing data in .NET, aside from using the `GZipStream` class.

I am looking for fast and high compression of byte arrays to be able to send them via TCP.

Comment: It would help if you explain why/if you don't like `GZipStream`.

Comment: Not saying that I do not like it - just looking for alternatives that might give me better performance and higher compression ratios. Commercial libraries are welcome as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) is an alternative. It's said that it's written more thoughtfully than the framework library GZipStream

Comment: SharpZipLib is unmaintained and buggy. Last release in June 2010. It sometimes has issues with zip files produced by 7zip, ioniczip, etc, even though the zip files are completely fine. We use it for a component at my work and have had to resort to fixing the source and building locally, which is not that big of a deal, but not something you want to have to get into if you are looking for a turnkey zip library.

Comment: @aggieNick02 Could you upload the fixed source code?

Comment: Sorry @mafu - I no longer have access to the changes we made

Answer (score 11):

If you are compressing *data*, then you might look at high-density serialization, rather than compression. Something like protobuf. There are a [few C# implementations here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns). For existing objects, protobuf-net is IMO the simplest to implement (disclosure: I'm the author - but it is free etc). You just serialize to the stream, or if you want a `byte[]`, a separate `MemoryStream`.

For *continuous* use over a socket (rather than the discreet request/response of HTTP), I would suggest looking at the `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix` / `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` operations (protobuf doesn't *itself* include a terminator, so a length-prefix is necessary to handle separate messages).

Comment: Marc, what does "high-density serialization" mean, especially in contrast to compression? Does it make use of any compression scheme or is it just an efficient way to represent data? Could you give a short explanation or any pointer to read on?

Comment: @0xA3 - what I mean is: if this is typical app data (that you might represent as xml or JSON), then use a different serializer to write the same data in less bytes. So instead of `<AccountId>123</AccountId>`, write 2 or 3 bytes instead. Not suitable for *arbitrary* `byte[]` though.

Comment: @MarcGravell What if there are many and/or large strings being serialized? Does ProtoBuf compress streamed strings?

Comment: @Todd no, the protobuf specification makes no mention of compression. What we do in those cases is simply: gzip the resultant payload

Answer (score 9):

<s>DotNetZip offers native support and has a quite friendly API and is my opinion more flexible than SharpZipLib:</s>

> **[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)**

EDIT: Unfortunately, *DotNetZip* has some critical issues and the project seems no longer be actively be maintained. Therefore, this library can't really be recommended for use in production code.

Better alternatives would be to use SharpZipLib (if you comply with their GPL-based license), one of the [.NET ports of zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14215168/40347) or the zip support of .NET 4.5 as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14215168/40347).

Comment: I made bad experiences with DotNetZip, it can't open Zip-archives which are perfectly openable with other libraries. It throws e.g. OverflowException for some reason, which I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @lama12345: Thanks for pointing this out. By now, I'm also well aware of the DotNetZip issues as those have bitten me as well. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Cheeso: Any updates about the future of the DotNetZip project? Is there any way the project can be supported?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3+ has built-in Zip support now, with the [ZipPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx) class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only offers some sort of zip support. It allows you to create zip-based "packages", but these packages are not pure zip files but packages as described by the OpenPackaging Conventions (OPC-format). These packages consist of PackagePart and PackageRelationship elements. This format is probably best known as the container format used by the Office OpenXML format.

Comment: What about IONIC zip library ?

Answer (score 1):

LZMA is supposed to be among the best for compression.  7-Zip is a public domain SDK implementation of LZMA, freely downloadable here:

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

[Wikipedia on compression algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR#Comparison_to_other_compression_algorithms):

> 7z's LZMA algorithm reaches a higher
>   compression ratio than RAR, except for
>   "multimedia" files like .wav and .bmp
>   files where RAR uses specialized
>   routines that outperform LZMA.[7] 
>   Other free compression software such
>   as NanoZip and FreeArc usually
>   outperform WinRAR.[8]

Comment: Im a big fan of 7-zip but not sure how accessible the api is.

Comment: The link points to LZMA SDK which has a C# API, and is public domain.

Comment: Sadly, the C# SDK was not updated in 10 years and does not support LZMA2.

Comment: I want to take this post down, but I just don't want to lose the 10 points, LOL/sigh.